# Java JUnit Test Simulate Next calculated number

Tags: java, junit

I am a student learning JUnit testing. When I add a new contact, it gets the next sequential number, converts in into a string, and then makes that the contact id.

My question is with the JUnit testing. The contact id has to be a string and cannot be longer than 10 characters. The test works fine for the actual next number since the arraylist has only a couple elements. How do I simulate the next number creating a string that is too long?

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Add a new contact
 * @param firstName, lastName, phone, address
 * id is generated
 */
public static void addContact(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String address) {
    
    Contact newContact = null;
    
    // Determine the next contact id & then change it to a string
    long nextContact = Contact.getNextContactId();
    String newId = String.valueOf(nextContact);
    
    newContact = new Contact(newId, firstName, lastName, phone, address);
    contacts.add(newContact);
    System.out.println("Contact " + newContact.getId() + " successfully added");
}
```

And the test (which only runs 1 of 2 branches):

```
@Test
void testNextId() {
    Contact contact = new Contact("1234567890", "Abcdefghij", "Klmnopqrst", "1234567890", "1234 Main Street");
    // Next Id is too long
    String newId = "12345678901";
    Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
        Contact.getNextContactId();
    });
}
```

Any help is REALLY appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You can't do that easily because  you wrote hard to test code. Having static method calls quickly gets you there, as gaining control over the calls to static methods is albeit possible a complicated thing to achieve. So the real answer would be to avoid using static calls. Instead, you would need a helper class that generates such ids. And then you can pass in a mock of that class, instead of a real instance.

Comment: But thing is: you have to learn how to do that. I recommend you get a good tutorial on Mockito and start learning how that framework works and how it gets used to write tests that require such level of control.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the quick response. I will start looking at Mockito to see how to solve my issue. Thank you for that info! This is my first week using JUnit and I have not even heard of Mockito until now.

Comment: Yeah, I think your assignment isn't a good starting point. The initial usage of JUnit should rather be about using asserts and such things. That need to test that method to get wrong strings just makes things really complicated. Not the kind of exercise I would throw at newbies.